# Draw scaled picture over an Image

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I have a WPF image, and I'm trying to draw something on it (Lets say a smiley, 2 blue circles for eyes and and a red ellipse for the mouth).
I've made a small `Rectangle` over the image, and made it stretched.

```
<Grid Name="mGrid">
    <Rectangle Height="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Name="mImageFrame"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="0" />
</Grid >
```

I used a `DrawingBrush` to draw the circles in the rectangle.
Obviously this is wrong, because I have 2 problems:
1. The DrawingBrush seems to have a different scale. It will scale according to the largest item it's drawing.
2. I can only use one brush color.

So, how can I somehow draw over an image so it keeps the same proportions ?
And how can I use a different color for each shape ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put Shapes on a Canvas that overlays the Image, and put the whole thing in a Viewbox. This requires that you define absolute coordinates by either setting the Image's `Stretch` property to `None` (and thus force the Image size to that of its `Source`  bitmap) or explicitly set is `Width` or `Height`.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
               Stretch="None"/>
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="420" Canvas.Top="480"
                     Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            ... more shapes here ...
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: I need the whole thing to be resizeable by the user, so i can't use an absolute size.

Comment: Ok got it. The Viewbox itself sets the size of the whole container.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to put both the drawing and the `Image` into a `ViewBox` control. You can find out more about the `Viewbox` from the [Viewbox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) page at MSDN. Basically, it provides the same stretching capabilities as the `Image` control.

You *may* also like to view the [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: Yea, I saw that page, very simple one shape - one color, no re-sizing examples.